# How can I save a log of an Ubuntu server terminal on an external PC using SSH?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, login, perl

I am using a script to automatically log in to a server:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $host = "hostname";
my $usr = "my userid";
my $pwd = "my password";
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login($usr,$pwd);
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("ls -l /home/$usr");
```

I want to save a log of the terminal activity from every time I log in, but i want to save it to my computer, not in the server.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that from perl someone else will have to answer, but if you want to do it from the terminal session, I do this. In the terminal I hit Shift+Ctrl+A, which selects all the text in the buffer for that terminal session. I then paste it into geany and save it. If you are not getting the entire session you may want to increase the number of scrollback lines in Preferences.